# Electron app on Mac OSX, input for file selection

Tags: html, reactjs, macos, electron

We have an Electron (v4.0.1) based app (React) that opens up a standard file selection dialog using an `<input type="file"...>`. On Windows/Linux the file dialog will remain on-top of the main app UI when user clicks into the main app. However on a Mac (OSX) the main app UI will overlay the file-dialog (which is now gone from view) and the only way to refocus is to alt+tab until it appears.

Is there anyway we can avoid this behaviour and have the file-dialog remain top-focused when the user clicks into the main app (as in Windows/Linux)?

Comment: Why not use a [native file dialog](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback)? There you can pass your `BrowserWindow` instance and it stays as a modal on top of your app.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner - we went with your recommendation. Put your reply in as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tackle this problem, there is an Electron module which lets you create native (file) dialogs with your desired specs.

Creating a modal browser window without any filters (like directory opening, multi-selection or file type filters) is as simple as the following snippet:

```
const { dialog, remote } = require ("electron");

var selected = dialog.showOpenDialog (
    remote.getCurrentWindow (),
    { properties: ["openFile"] }
);

if (typeof selected === "undefined") {
    // Oh no! The user didn't select anything!
} else {
    // ...
}
```

[The documentation on `dialog`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) has some more sophisicated examples of using this API.